# PostgreSQL - Storing multiple versions of a service description

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am maintaining a web application which allows a user to upload web service descriptions. The service table to store those descriptions looks roughly like this:

```
CREATE TABLE service(
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar(255)
  targetNamespace varchar(255),
);
```

Now we want to enable the user to upload multiple versions of his web service. The question is how to reflect this in the database.

Here's my idea so far:

- have a service table but only store the service id

  ```
  CREATE TABLE service(
    id integer primary key,
  );
  ```
- have a service_version table which stores version specific information and references the service table using a FK:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE service_version(
    id integer primary key,
    service_id integer references service(id),
    name varchar(255),
    target_namespace varchar(255)
  );
  ```

This should enable me to query for all versions associated with service. Is this a sane approach? Are there better solutions?

Comment: Depending on how I expected my data to be queried, I'd probably do either exactly what you've got here, or leave `service` alone and make a `service_history` table with previous versions. Hopefully somebody has a real answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you need attributes in the SERVICE table other than an ID, in order to be able to uniquely identify an individual web service in an effective manner. For example, would the name not stay the same, and hence be an attribute of the SERVICE rather than the SERVICE_HISTORY?

Only the elements that might change between versions should be in the versions table, you see.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Made it more answerey and less commentey

Comment: +1 Good catch. The service name may in fact not change and thus is more suited to be part of the service table.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20073752/642706) by David Aldridge…

Your problem description is not perfectly clear. Are saying each web service is identified by a name, and over time each web service will have new versions developed where each version gets a new ID number and a possibly different namespace?

If so, this is precisely the same scenario as a book being published where the name remains the same while new editions may be published where each edition gets a new number and a possibly different subtitle.

This scenario would be a simple parent-child relationship. Define one table for the web services (the book), and a related child table for the versions (editions).

Diagrams

[image]

You will probably want one business rule to be enforced by your app programming and/or the database server's contstraints: Every parent (web service) must have at least one child, never zero. That first child of each parent represents the initial version.